# Using dd Command during boot to automate a task but service keeps failing, works when called after boot?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, dd

Ok so I am trying to automate a procedure that involves flashing and installing different linux images on some embedded sbc's. I am currently using a pxe image to boot into an embedded device and normally I wait for the pxe image to boot and then run a dd command that flashes the onboard harddrive with an image I have on my pxe-server via nfs. So this part works fine and dandy but as soon as I try to run this as a startup service it fails. It worked once just by luck somehow which is weird and makes me think there is some kind of timeout or race condition maybe, which is why I got lucky once and with the same setup it never worked again. I have approached it two ways rc-local.service as well as my own actual systemd service. here is my script and the service file. also I have enabled it and verified there is a link under multi-user.target.

```
#script at /usr/local/sbin/sysInstall
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/bin/bash

dd if=/mnt/nfs/RTE.img of=/dev/sda status=progress &>> /mnt/nfs/dd_out.txt

shutdown -r now
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#service file at /etc/systemd/system/sysInstall.service
[Unit]
Description=Load the image onto the harddrive from nfs

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/sysInstall

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

oh and yes I did chmod +x the file script at /usr/local/sbin no change though. I also put the scipt in /bin and I can run it after boot and it does fine so the script itself seems fine but the service always fails with

```
[root@station1 ~]# systemctl -l status sysInstall.service
● sysInstall.service - This service auto flashes the local harddrive
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sysInstall.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-10-04 20:37:35 CDT; 34s ago
  Process: 3573 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/sysINSTALL.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3573 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 04 20:37:35 station1 systemd[1]: Started This service auto flashes the local harddrive.
Oct 04 20:37:35 station1 systemd[1]: Starting This service auto flashes the local harddrive...
Oct 04 20:37:35 station1 systemd[1]: sysInstall.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 04 20:37:35 station1 systemd[1]: Unit sysInstall.service entered failed state.
Oct 04 20:37:35 station1 systemd[1]: sysInstall.service failed.
```

last interesting notes the system will reboot with this script in so its like it does get in there but fails the dd and jumps to the restart ? doesn't make since to me thought bash was one after the other so if dd failed why does it keeps moving on. so I commented out the restart so I could diagnose the issue and got the above.
if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong or things to try that would be really awesome thanks.

after editing my service file as recommended I had this as an output.I also saw that the nfs /mnt/nfs was mounted at the very end of the boot like right before the login was launched so I need to make the unit wait until it recieves that condition true and then start perhaps?

```
[root@station1 ~]# systemctl -l status sysInstall.service
● sysInstall.service - This service auto flashes the local harddrive
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sysInstall.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Thu 2018-10-04 20:18:32 CDT; 5min ago
           ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/nfs was not met

Oct 04 20:18:32 station1 systemd[1]: Started This service auto flashes the local harddrive.
```

I am looking into systemd timers to use the OnBootSec= as a way to repeated try the condition as a work around?

Comment: That `dd` command writes 512 byte blocks. If you're writing to anything modern you probably want a _minimum_ of a 4kiB block size, and quite possibly 16MiB or even more. On full Linux-based systems `cat` can be a better bet, but if this is a busybox boot just put a decent block size on `dd`

Comment: so your right the default is 512 but the img file I am copying is like 16 GB, and it works when running it after boot, would the block size be important during boot? I will change it to 4k just to see if it makes a difference, especially since it worked 1 single time and never before that instance and never again so  I feel like it could be a timing issues of a sort?

Comment: No not during boot. I don't have an answer for that. It's simply that if you've got 4kB blocks on your target you're potentially making four writes per block where one would do

Comment: You should setup your systemd service unit to require that networking and the NFS mount be available before attempting to start.  In the `[Unit]` section add the lines `ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/nfs` and `After=network-online.target`, then see if it works any better.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and seems to have made some progress see my edited question

Comment: Is `/mnt/nfs` mounted? What do you see in `/mnt/nfs/dd_out.txt`?  Did you try running this w/o the redirection?

Comment: What are you using to mount `/mnt/nfs`?  Add that service to the `After=` line to make sure your service only starts after the path is mounted.